# Complex integration verification

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $C$ be the arc from $z = 0$ to $z = 1 + i$ along the curve $y = x^2$. Evaluate and simplify the following:

(a) $$ \int_C Re(z)dz$$

I got $\frac{1}{2}$ and I believe this is right.

(b) $$ \int_C z^3dz$$

I got $-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{19}{40}i$. I did this through parameterization and I can't find my mistake but the answer does not look right.  Obviously you can not have negative area in real analysis but how does translate into complex? Does it at all? I can't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both integrals are computed along $C:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb C$, with $C(t)=t+it^2$. Note that $C(0)=0$ and $C(1)=1+i$.
The first one is then equal to

$$\int_C \operatorname{Re}(z)dz=\int_0^1 t \cdot(1+2ti)dt=1+\frac{2}{3}i, $$

as $C'(t)=1+2ti$.
The second one reads

$$\int_C z^3dz= \int_0^1 t^3(1+3ti-3t^2-it^3)\cdot(1+2ti)dt=\frac{1}{4}+i-\frac{3}{2}
-i +\frac{1}{4}=-1 $$

instead.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I forgot the dz.

Comment: You are welcome:al you need is just the definition of the line integral and a bit of patience to write down all monomials. Feel free to flag and upvote if it was useful